# command exists but not found in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script, script.sh:

```
`echo $1 $2`
```

When I run `script.sh hd file` I get the error:

```
script.sh[1]: hd: not found
```

But when I run `hd file` in the command line the command runs successfully. How come inside the bash script the command does not exist and outside the script it does exist?

Comment: just delete `` and try `echo $1 $2`

Answer (score -1):

i think u just need to modify

```
echo '$1 $2'
```

and than run this might solve

yaah but the main role of that backticks is that it executes commands in backticks before main command